# Is nesting iterators inside each other expectable where for loops would break

Tags: java, nested, hashmap, iterator, hashset

Would you consider it good or bad to nest iterators like this?

**Context:** for loop version breaks because I am appending synonyms at same time as using it in a for loop.

```
// HashSet inside HashMap
HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> synonyms = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();

// loops through synonyms 
Iterator word = synonyms.keySet().iterator();

while(word.hasNext()) {
    // loops through synonyms 
    Iterator line = synonyms.get(word.next().toString()).iterator();

    while(line.hasNext()) {
        // adds to Synonyms, this breaks for loop version
        addToSynonyms(word, line.next())
    }
}
```

Alternatively in the for loop versions I could make a copy of the HashMap<String, HashSet> and feed the copy to the for loop and append only the original but would the above be cleaner?

Thank you

Edited hopefully a better example below.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.HashMap;


// examples of looping through HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> numbersAndWords;
// 
public class Example {
    
    HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> numbersAndWords;

    public Example() {
        numbersAndWords = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();
        
        // data
        numbersAndWords.put("five", new HashSet<>());
        numbersAndWords.get("five").add(("1 2 3 4 5"));
    }

    
    /** 
     * uses two iterators to loop through numbersAndWords and adds to numbersAndWords without breaking loops
     */
    public void exampleOne() {

        // loops through HashMap Strings of words "five"
        Iterator words = numbersAndWords.keySet().iterator();
        
        while(words.hasNext()) {

            // loops through HashSet Strings of numbers "1 2 3 4 5"
            Iterator numbers = numbersAndWords.get(words.next().toString()).iterator();
            while(numbers.hasNext()) {

                // data is arbitrary reason for exmaple is this appends
                // numbersAndWords which breaks the for loop 
                // Their for I have to use an iterator but should I be using to
                // or have things in a different format
                numbersAndWords.put("three", new HashSet<>());
                numbersAndWords.get("three").add(("1, 2, 3"));
                
                numbers.next();
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Example example = new Example();
            example.exampleOne();
        }

}
```

Currently looking into replacing the first itr with a for loop using HashMap.size() so it wont break when I append HashMap later.

Thank you

Comment: Evaluating code as generically "good" or "bad" is as clear a matter of opinion as can be.  Questions soliciting opinions are off topic here.  As a personal viewpoint, however, I find the code presented very difficult to follow.

Comment: Thank you for the feed back that makes senses the "good" or "bad" may be my autism coming out.

Comment: Any thoughts on how I can make this more readable? Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify/explain what you try to achieve with this code?  What does method `addToSynonyms` implement?  What is the purpose of _adding a synonym_ `line.next()` to _iterator_ `word`?  Please also be aware that you should not use _raw_ iterators and use `toString`, if the map/nested sets are properly typed

Comment: It would be made somewhat more readable by (i) using the `entrySet` or even the `values` collection instead of the `keySet` for the outer loop; and (ii) avoiding burying calls to `Iterator.next()` inside method invocations.  Using enhanced `for` loops would help, too, but that's not an option when you are modifying a collection while iterating over it.  But depending on which collections you are actually modifying, you might be able to use a `for` loop in place of *one* of the iterators.

Comment: A [mre] with a small sample of input with the expected output would help.

Comment: Note that it seems unlikely to me that the iterators are actually helping anything.  The only point I can see to using them instead of enhanced `for` loops would be that you want to use them to modify the collection(s) being iterated while iteration is in progress (via the iterator to avoid breakage), but the only modification `java.util.Iterator` itself provides is `remove()`.  If that is both necessary and sufficient to support a method named `addToSynonyms()`, then that name must be rather ill-fitting.

Comment: @AlexRudenko I have added what will hopefully be a better example. Thats right its to iterator both line and word in original example. Your right in the original example their is no clear end result to doing this rather I am trying to understand how best to structure my two loops as at the end of the loops they append the same data type as the loop is running on which means I cannot use for loops. Thank you

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you I will research this and try and write an answer following your suggestions specification.

Comment: @WJS Thank you hopefully the new example helps my main aim is to not break the loops but organize them in the neatest way possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of this code is still a bit vague even after the latest updates.

If some *new* data need to be created and appended to the original map `numbersAndWords`, and they depend *somehow* on the current state of the original map, then a new temporary map has to be created and populated (using enhanced `for` loops, Stream API with `map/flatMap`, whatever).  When done, the contents of this new map may be added to the original one, using `Map::putAll`:

```java
public void exampleOne() {
    Map<String, HashSet<String>> toAppend = new HashMap<>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, HashSet<String>> me : numbersAndWords.entrySet()) {
        for (String str : me.getValue()) {
            System.out.println("Appending for key: " + me.getKey() + "; value=" + str);
            toAppend.computeIfAbsent("three", k -> new HashSet<>())
                    .add("1 2 3"); // or whatever is really needed
        }
    }
    numbersAndWords.putAll(toAppend);

    System.out.println(numbersAndWords);
}
```

Assuming that the original map is set up like this:

```java
public Example() {
    numbersAndWords = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();
        
    // data
    numbersAndWords.computeIfAbsent("five", k -> new HashSet<>()).add("1 2 3 4 5");
    numbersAndWords.computeIfAbsent("five", k -> new HashSet<>()).add("5 4 3 2 1");
    numbersAndWords.computeIfAbsent("four", k -> new HashSet<>()).add("1 2 3 4");
}
```

The output is as follows when invoking `new Example().exampleOne();`:

```
Appending for key: four; value=1 2 3 4
Appending for key: five; value=1 2 3 4 5
Appending for key: five; value=5 4 3 2 1
{four=[1 2 3 4], five=[1 2 3 4 5, 5 4 3 2 1], three=[1 2 3]}
```

---

However, such population of hardcoded values is pretty meaningless because no duplicate entries can be created in the map for a hardcoded key as well as adding the same values to a set is useless.

Comment: Absolutely perfect thank you very much.